# Is the inverse fourier transfrom of an analytic function itself analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $F(k)$ is analytic and $f(z)$ is the inverse Fourier transform of $F(k)$. Is $f$ then analytic in its domain?

Comment: Consider the $\mathrm{sinc}$/box function pair.

Comment: Does this provide a counter example?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider the [Paley-Wiener theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem).